# How does swift infer that num1 and num2 are integers?

Tags: xcode, swift, closures, type-inference

I am confused on how Swift infers that `num1` and `num2` are Integers. The function is accepting an array of Ints, true, but how does swift now that `num1` and `num2` are related to the array of Ints???

```
func mean4 (numbers: [ Int ] ) -> Double {

let sum = numbers.reduce(0, combine: { num1, num2 in 

return num1 + num2 04: })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reduce` function is defined as:

```
extension SequenceType {
    public func reduce<T>(initial: T, @noescape combine: (T, Self.Generator.Element) -> T) -> T
}
```

Self.Generator.Element refers to the array element type, which is Int. This means `num2` is an Int. From the initial value `0` you passed, it can infer that `T` is an Int as well.

Comment: this is the reduce function? I haven't learned that yet.....Its so confusing as a  beginner when clearly the chapter says it is only basic, this book is supposed to teach step by step, how can it jump to the reduce() like that without even explaining the definition of the function, all it does is say that this function iterates over elements in an array, it just generalizes it.....?

Comment: You can find this by ⌘-clicking on `reduce` from your code. Once you learn about protocols, sequences, generics, and closures, it'll make sense!

Comment: the book still hasn't covered those yet.....is it still safe to continue even though I don't have a good understanding of this reduce()?

Comment: Absolutely! I would say the point of `reduce` is to learn about functional programming concepts, not to learn the gory details of how it works in Swift. This is a common concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Answer (score 3):

**num2**

Because `numbers` array is type `[Int]`, it knows that `num2` or the next element will be an `Int`.

**num1**

Because your starting value is `0`, it infers that the reduction value, or `num1` is also an `Int`